# Displaying the values from the session array

Tags: c#, asp.net, session, web, web-deployment

i am new to asp.net and c# . i am using a session array to store list of values in to the session. but when i try to display the values using response.write method, it does not give the exact values in the session instead it says "System.Collections.ArrayList". the code i used to add values in the session is shown below.

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{

    if (Session["Cart"] == null)
    {
        Session["Cart"] = new ArrayList();
    }

    else
    {
        ArrayList cart = (ArrayList)Session["Cart"];
    }


}

protected void addtocart_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    int dealid = Convert.ToInt32(Request.QueryString.Get("deal"));
    ArrayList cart1 = new ArrayList();

    cart1 = (ArrayList)Session["Cart"];

    cart1.Add(dealid);

    Session["Cart"] = cart1;

    Response.Write(Session["Cart"].ToString());
}
```

}

can anyone  help me to display the values that are stored inside the session. please..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't `response.write(Session["Cart"].Tostring())` because `Session["Cart"]` is ArrayList. You have to loopthrough that arraylist before response.write like below:

```
protected void addtocart_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{

int dealid = Convert.ToInt32(Request.QueryString.Get("deal"));
ArrayList cart1 = new ArrayList();

cart1 = (ArrayList)Session["Cart"];

cart1.Add(dealid);

Session["Cart"] = cart1;

ArrayList cart2 = new ArrayList();

cart2 = (ArrayList)Session["Cart"];
foreach(var item in cart2 )
{
  Response.WriteLine(item);
}
```

}

Answer (score 2):

You need to make a loop for show all value in the session.

```
private ArrayList cart
{
    get
    {
        if (Session["Cart"] == null)
        {
            Session["Cart"] = new ArrayList();
        }
        return (ArrayList)Session["Cart"];
    }
    set
    {
        Session["Cart"] = value;
    }
}

protected void addtocart_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    int dealid = Convert.ToInt32(Request.QueryString.Get("deal"));
    cart.Add(dealid);
    foreach (var item in cart)
    {
        Response.Write(item.ToString());
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Because you placed ArrayList into Session. And then it returned it to you when you call Session["Cart"]. If you want to display all items from that list, then you need to iterate them like this:

```
protected void addtocart_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    int dealid = Convert.ToInt32(Request.QueryString.Get("deal"));
    ArrayList cart1 = new ArrayList();

    cart1 = (ArrayList)Session["Cart"];

    cart1.Add(dealid);

    Session["Cart"] = cart1;

    // iterate items in session
    ArrayList cart = Session["Cart"] as ArrayList;
    foreach(var item in cart)
    {
        Response.Write(item.ToString());
    }
}
```

One more thing, that using

```
List<int>
```

is more useful and better that ArrayList, because you don't need to cast objects to needed type.

Answer (score 0):

There is no need to assign cart1 back to session in `Session["Cart"] = cart1;`. To print dealid, you need to write something like `Response.Write(Session["Cart"][0].ToString());`

Answer (score 0):

Iterate over arraylist and build the necessary string.

```
StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
foreach(var obj in cart1)
{
  sb.Append(obj.ToString())
}
Response.Write(sb.ToString());
```

Answer (score 0):

There is a debug functionality inside Visual Studio. Set breakpoints in your code. Run your project and step through your code using F10 or F11. Click on a value and see it's content. More information? [See this](http://www.dotnetperls.com/debugging)

Answer (score 0):

For display arraylist item from the array you use below code:

```
 foreach (var item in (ArrayList)Session["Cart"])
 {
            Response.Write(item);
 }
```